# Using malloc to create a linked list

Tags: malloc

i used malloc in order to allocate new nodes in the list,yet i am facing an error with a certain part of my code;
the following solution applies only to deleting and inserting

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct Node{
    int value;
    struct Node * Next;
    struct Node * Previous;


};
typedef struct Node Node;
struct List{
    int Count;
    int Total;
    Node * First;
    Node * Last;
};
typedef struct List List;
List Create();
void Add(List a,int value);
void Remove(List a,Node * b);
List Create()
{
    List a;
    a.Count=0;
    return a;

}

void Add(List a,int value)
{
    Node * b = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(b==NULL)
        printf("Memory allocation error \n");
    b->value=value;
    if(a.Count==0)
    {
        b->Next=NULL;
        b->Previous=NULL;
        a.First=b;

    }
    else
    {
        b->Next=NULL;
        b->Previous=a.Last;
        a.Last->Next=b;

    }
    ++a.Count;
    a.Total+=value;
    a.Last=b;
    }
void Remove(List a,Node * b)
{
    if(a.Count>1)
    {
        if(a.Last==b)
        {
            b->Previous->Next=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            b->Previous->Next=b->Next;
            b->Next->Previous=b->Previous;
        }

        }
    free(b);
    }
```

in the delete function,in the last else condition,i am not certain whether or not using b->Next->Previous is okay,and will work;when using the -> operator,am i adressing to the node pointer or to it's value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: Yes, `b->Next->Previous` is fine -- it's a `struct Node*`, just like the right hand side `b->Previous`.

I think that your error lies with the handling of `Count`: It is incremented by `Add()`, but `Remove()` doesn't decrement it. In fact, as the list itself only needs to know whether it is empty or not, you can remove it and instead see if `a.First == NULL`. (Your `a.Count == 1` test can likewise be replaced with `a.First != NULL && a.First->Next == NULL` test.)

If you're promising `Count` in you API, you can add it back when you've got the list itself working. The same "remove-then-add-back" might be useful with `Total`. Think of both of these as caches.

An even better solution would be to implement a circular list:

```
struct List
{
    Node Anchor;
    //...
};

List Create()
{
    List l;
    l.Anchor.Next = l.Anchor.Previous = &l;
    return l;
}

bool IsEmpty(List const* l)
{
    // Both or neither point at 'l'.
    assert((l->Anchor.Next == l) == (l->Anchor.Previous == l));
    return l->Anchor.Next == l;
}

// Add a node 'n' to some list after 'ln'.
void AddAfter(Node* n, Node* ln)
{
    n->Previous = ln;
    n->Next = ln->Next;
    n->Next->Previous = n->Previous->Next = n;
}

Node* Remove(Node* n)
{
   n->Previous->Next = n->Next;
   n->Next->Previous = n->Previous;
   n->Next = n->Previous = n;  // nice and proper
   return x;
}
```

Now you longer need special cases for empty lists. I let `Remove()` return the node itself, to make it easy to either move nodes between lists (`AddAfter(Remove(somenode), &otherlist.Anchor)`) or remove and delete notes (`free(Remove(somenode))`).

One wart here is that my `Anchor` node now wastes space for data that never will be used -- but that is easily fixable.

Comment: Great!Thank you very much.i fixed the counters and total sum as those are required in my code.an additional question;if i would like to use list.remove(node *) instead of remove(list,node *),how can that be done?(as the list is not a class in which i can apply functions).

Comment: how can i convert the function to operate as List.Remove(node) instead if Remove(List,node)?

Comment: First switch from C to C++ -- your use of `malloc()`, `free()`, and `typedef struct Node Node` made me recognize your code sample as C.

Comment: If you want to stay in C, a "roll your own vtbl" style of member functions is quite doable, but you have to do all the work yourself (some smart macros might help you out); work that will teach you the nuts and bolts of object orientation. A meta-note: Please make it a real question, so you can get proper answers -- the comment field isn't really meant for that.

Comment: okay,but the current code is correct,right?i will be glad to receive an explanation to making a vtbl style of member function.

Comment: Yes, it is (if it works)? The "roll-your-own-vtbl" style simply means that (some of) your struct members are function pointers that you initialize in `Create()` and then simply call it as (let's say) `obj->Func(obj);`. Again, make your query a real question if you want a more detailed answer.